# Play sound <audio> HTML 5 till mouse move

Tags: jquery

There is way with jquery to mute sound on mouse movement?

```
<audio src="music/file.mp3" autoplay loop></audio>
```

thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "mouse move?" hover?

Comment: user move his mouse.. touch his mouse.

Comment: Using jQuery, `$("body").mouseover(function(){ /* Stop the audio */ });`

Comment: $.each($('audio'), function () {
    this.stop();
}); this is the right way to stop the audio?

Comment: `.stop()` has nothing to do with audio.

Answer (score 0):

Put an id on your audio

```
<audio id="audio1" src="music/file.mp3" autoplay loop></audio>
```

Then use `mousemove` event to mute, and set a timer to restore sound if mouse stops moving

```
$(function(){

    var t;
    $("body").mousemove(function(){

        clearTimeout(t); //Clear restore volume function

        //Mute
        var audio = document.getElementById("audio1");
        audio.volume=0.0;

        //Time restore volume
        t = setTimeout(function(){
            var audio = document.getElementById("audio1");
            audio.volume=1.0;
        }, 200);
    });
});
```

You don't need to use jQuery to work with `<audio>`: [w3schools audio/video](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp)